# edit css style of an element with a space in its class name

Tags: html, css, space, tumblr

I'm creating a tumblr them and I have to write an external CSS file but I am having trouble editing the css style of the post elements.

This its structure:

```
<li class="post quote">
    {other code}
</li>
```

The problem is that the class name has a space in it.
How would I create a CSS class to access this? And yes, I know I can just put a style attribute in the element tag but I was kind of hoping for another option.

Comment: That would ordinarily be interpreted as two classes, which you can select with .post.quote (or .quote.post), though some versions of IE have issues with it.

Comment: See [similar question, with more clues about how browsers must to interpret multiple class names](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13808846/287948).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> The problem is that the class name has a space in it.

This is not possible in CSS. What you are doing is giving the element *two* classes.

You can address them such:

```
.post.quote { .... }
```

but in your case, it's probably better to use a valid separator like

```
post_quote
```

Comment: It is an *override by class name*... But you say "This is not possible in CSS"?? InDesign5+ do this, and a lot of web-designers... There are a W3C rule that say "it is not valid"?

Comment: @Peter class names with spaces are impossible - how would you refer to them? Consider `.class name { font-size: 10px }` - `class` refers to a class, and `name` to a sub-element. It's not possible, try it out.

Comment: Yes, `class="a b"` is not a unique class name, like `class="a_b"`. My question is about the expected override effect in the HTML renderizarion (`b` overrides `a` in this example)... There are a W3C valid standard? Or it is an Adobe Indesign (export HTML) invention?

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure what you mean by "override" exactly?

Comment: Example: at css definition we have ".a { font-weight: bold;} .b { font-weight: normal;}", and at HTML body we have `<p class="a b">not bold text</p>`... So, IF browser renders with normal text, we can say that class `b` overrides `a`. Well, my browser not do this always... OK, I am submitting a new question, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/13808846/287948

Comment: @Peter ahh, I see now. No, as far as I know, that should never be valid

Answer (score 2):

This element actually has *two* classes - it is marked with both the `post` class *and* the `quote` class.  So, you can use the following selectors to access it:

```
// css
.post { ... }   // elements with the post class
.quote { ... }  // elements with the quote class

// jQuery
var postLis = $('.post');
var quoteLis = $('.quote');
```

You can also stack selectors to return all elements which meet all conditions in the selector, by including the different selectors together:

```
// css
.post.quote { ... }  // elements with both the post and quote classes

// jQuery
var postAndQuoteLis = $('.post.quote');
```

Comment: I'm not using jQuery though. How would I do that in CSS: .post .quote { }?

Comment: The selectors (the bits in the quote marks above) are the same in css

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
$('li').each(function() {     
    if($(this).attr('class').indexOf(" ")>-1) {
       $(this).css('border','1px solid #ff0000')
    }  
}
```