# python Ghost.py unsuported field tag error

Tags: python, error-handling, ghost.py

```html
<div class="Rd" guidedhelpid="sharebox_editor">
<div class="eg">
<div class="yw oo"></div>
<div class="yw VK"></div>
</div>
<div class="URaP8 Kf Pf b-K b-K-Xb">
<div id="207" class="pq">Share what's new...</div>
<div id=":3s.f" class="df b-K b-K-Xb URaP8 editable"   contenteditable="true"g_editable="true" role="textbox" aria-labelledby="207"></div>
```

What I'm doing is this:

```
ghost.set_field_value(".df.b-K.b-K-Xb.URaP8.editable[role=textbox]", "jeanphix")
```

I'm getting an "unsupported field tag" error

Comment: Why are you replacing the spaces with dots? I'd expect something like the answer to this question instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596314/jquery-ids-with-spaces

Comment: beccause "df b-K b-K-Xb URaP8 editable"is class selector i think space must replace with dot

Comment: yup.. you're right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695812/edit-css-style-of-an-element-with-a-space-in-its-class-name

Answer (score 0):

Based on the github source, your element is being found (otherwise you'd get a "can\'t find element for " error) However, ghost.py allows only certain HTML tags for use with the `set_field_value(..)` method: select, textarea, and input (of various types).

Since you're you're attempting it on a DIV, it throws the unsupported tag error exception. The "raise" is on line 830 on the current version in github: https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py/blob/dev/ghost/ghost.py Check out the if/else statements preceding that and you should be able to see what I mean

Comment: no i dont understand i just want post in g00gle plus page im able login and  click on popup frame then i got stuck im new to programming

Comment: Then you'll have to select another method. This one only allows certain HTML tags and DIV is not one of them. There are plenty of alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292817/how-to-automate-browsing-using-python If you're new to programming then a browser plug-in may be more appropriate: http://www.greasespot.net/ but your question was about this particular error in this particular library.